# Symfony2 remember_me User provider

Tags: symfony

At the moment im working on a Symfony2 project using 2 user providers. I want to use the the remember_me functionality. Is there a way to specifiy which user provider should be used?

Actually the remember me Service always loads the wrong provider.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem ... it is quite simple just add user_provider: provider_name to the config

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and accept it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem ... it is quite simple just add user_provider: provider_name to the config